# Mudar imagem sprite quando botão for clicado no unity

Tags: c#, unity-5

Eu preciso que quando um botão for clicado, se a resposta estiver correta a imagem (um arbusto) mude (para uma vaca na frente do arbusto).

```
public class mudaSprite : MonoBehaviour {

public InputField dgt;
public Text txt;
public Sprite arbusto;
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();


public void setget(){

    if (dgt.text.ToLower().Equals("cinza")) {
        if (spriteRenderer.sprite == null) {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("vacarbustoC");
        }
        ChangeTheDamnSprite ();

        txt.text = "";
    } 
    else {
        txt.text="Tente Novamente!";
    }
}

void ChangeTheDamnSprite(){
    if (spriteRenderer.sprite == arbusto) {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("vacarbustoC");
    } else {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = arbusto;
    }
}
```

pleaaase!!

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui!!!

Coloquei os arbustos fora do canvas, como GameObject. Então coloquei o código acima associado ao GameObject e não aos sprites.